# Show Process In Linux Using C++

Tags: c++, linux, process

I am starting in C++, reading a good book of it and I want to build a program that shows the user all the process that the Linux of he is doing, using C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the library

http://procps.sourceforge.net/

For reading proc entries would be useful. This is how `top` and others gain access to a list of running process.

Also see a similar question:

> [Linux API to list running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes)

You can also link to the **libproc** library rather than copying source from procps.