# How to get the PID of a process in Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, process

I need to kill a process using the kill API. For that I need the process id of the process. I tried to get it using:

```
ret = system("pidof -s raj-srv");
```

but it is not returning the correct value. I dont want to kill the process using this:

```
ret = system("pkill raj");
```

Is there any API that could be used to get the process id?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes

Answer (score 22):

You are getting the return status of `system`. That's not the pid. You want something like this:

```
char line[LEN];
FILE *cmd = popen("pidof...", "r");

fgets(line, LEN, cmd);
pid_t pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);

pclose(cmd);
```

Answer (score 5):

There could be multiple instances of processes running in that case , pidof returns strings of pid seperated by space .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
        char pidline[1024];
        char *pid;
        int i =0;
        int pidno[64];
        FILE *fp = popen("pidof bash","r");
        fgets(pidline,1024,fp);

        printf("%s",pidline);
        pid = strtok (pidline," ");
        while(pid != NULL)
                {

                        pidno[i] = atoi(pid);
                        printf("%d\n",pidno[i]);
                        pid = strtok (NULL , " ");
                        i++;
                }
     
        pclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `system()` call doesn't return the output of `pidof`, it returns `pidof`'s return code, which is zero if it succeeds.

You could consume the output of `pidof` using `popen()` instead of `system()`, but I'm sure there's a better way (the way `pidof` itself uses). Perhaps it wanders through `/proc`.

Comment: Yes, `opendir` and `readdir` `/proc`. But not all Unixes have `/proc`.

Comment: @cnicutar: True, but they also probably don't have `pidof`.

Comment: Maybe, but they *will* have `ps` and `grep`.

Comment: @cnicutar: No disagreement there. My point was that if you're happy to use `pidof`, then using `/proc` probably won't worry you.

Answer (score 1):

What is returned by the `system` function is the return code from the command being executed.

What you can do is something like this:

```
system("pidof -s raj-srv > /tmp/pid-of-raj-srv");
```

And then read the contents of the file `/tmp/pid-of-raj-srv`.

Comment: `popen` is a better way, because it does not need to create a temporary file

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not a fresh thread, but as I have only recently faced the same question, I will ask you. Did you see one of this:

- [Get process id by name in C](http://programming-in-linux.blogspot.com.br/2008/03/get-process-id-by-name-in-c.html)
- [C function to find a process ID and kill it](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/c-function-to-find-a-process-id-and-kill-it-65395.html)
- [man sysctl(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sysctl/)

You can use `sysctl` to give you the needed information without having to pass through a `system( "bla, bla" )` call.
It seems to be far more complicated at first, but may be worth depending on your needs.

Comment: That first link is broken. The second link says `sysctl()` isn't the thing to use for Linux, but `opendir()` and `readdir()` of `/proc` instead.