# Get PID, when have program name fragment

Tags: c, linux, pid, ps

I need to kill java process, that runs main class blabla.class. I can use function `kill(pid_t, SIGKILL)` for this reason, but I need to get `PID ID`.

I could run linux command `ps-ax | grep blabla` to find PID ID. What is the best way to do this using C ?

Comment: You can either run `ps` in a subprocess, or troll through the per-process subdirectories of the /proc directory yourself, checking each /proc/###/cmdline against your pattern of interest.

Comment: `man pgrep`, `man pkill`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the PID of a process in Linux in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166415/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-in-linux-in-c)

Comment: I think this is not an exact dup of @Marco's suggestion because of the "fragment" part of the question. But you could adapt the code given there to do the `ps -ax | grep blabla` and look at the returned string.

Comment: `PID ID` is nice ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the link given by Marco https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166467/1967396:

```
#define LEN 100
char line[LEN];
FILE *cmd = popen("ps -ax | grep blabla", "r");

fgets(line, LEN, cmd);
// now parse `line` for the information you want, using sscanf perhaps?
// I believe the pid is the first word on the line returned, and it fits in an int:
int pid;
sscanf(line, "%d", &pid);

pclose(cmd);
```