# How to get the pid of another process in c?

Tags: c, linux, system, embedded-linux

I am using the getpid and get the pid of current process. Now I am try to get the pid of other process using process name. How to get the other process pid?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("My pid:%d\n", getpid());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166415/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-in-linux-in-c

Comment: Apart from the below answer other method can be writing your own kernel module and interacting with it. <-- (its lot of work but give you the id). You can also run a shell script which parses ps command and get you the pid. You can figure out more ways ..... i guess !!

Answer (score 7):

You could use `popen()` with the command program `pidof` to get the `pid` of any program.

Like this:

```
char line[total_length];
FILE * command = popen("pidof ...","r");

fgets(line,total_length,command);

pid_t pid = strtoul(line,NULL,10);
pclose(command);
```

Edit:

Please see: [How to get the PID of a process in Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166415/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-in-linux-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

1: The most common way, used by daemons. Store the pid number in a file/files. Then other processes can easily find them.

2: Portable way, spawn a child process to executes `ps` with a pipe. Then you can parse the text output and find your target process.

3: Non-portable way, parse the /proc/ filesystem

Often, 1 is combined with 2 or 3, in order to verify that the pid is correct.