# Information about file on Linux system?

Tags: c, linux

I want known if a determinate file is in use by process, i.e. if file is open in read-only mode by that process.

I thought about searching through /proc/[pid]/[fd] directory, but this way I waste a lot of time, and I think that doing this is not beautiful.

Is there any way using some Linux API to determinate if X file is open by any process? Or maybe some structures data like /proc but for files?

Comment: Good question. Looking at the sources of `lsof` should point you to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining if a process is using a file is easy.  The inverse less so.  The reason is that the kernel does not keep track of the inverse directly.  The information that IS kept is:

1. A file knows how many links refer to itself (inode table)
2. A processes knows what files it has open (file descriptor table)

This is why `lsof`'s /proc walking is necessary.  The file descriptors in use by a particular process are kept in /proj/$PID (among other things), and so lsof can use this (and other things) to spit out all of the pid <-> fd <-> inode relationships.

[This is a nice article on `lsof`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html).  As with any Linux util, you can always check out its source code for all of the details :)

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of. The `lsof` and `fuser` tools do precisely what you suggest, wander through `/proc/*/fd`.

Note that it is possible for open files to not have a name, if the file was deleted after being opened, and it is possible for a file to be open without the process holding a file descriptor (through `mmap`), and even the combination of both (this would be a process-private swap file that is automatically cleaned up on process exit).

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` might be the tool you're searching for.

**EDIT**: I din't realize you are specifically searching for something to be integrated in your application, so my answer appears a little simplistic. But anyway, I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes) is pretty much related to yours.

Comment: Thing is, `lsof` walks `/proc`.

Comment: yeah, it might be implemented like that. So?

Comment: The OP said "it's not beautiful".

Comment: "it's not beautiful" to be done manually because it is time-consuming, I suppose

Comment: Thanks to everybody for answer my question. I see that solution is walking through /proc directory, and search information that i want. 

I liked your technical answer, now i understand a little more how kernel works with processes and files. Thanks a lot!