# How can I detect when I'm on a system running Unity?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-unity

In order to choose between what type of app indicators to use for a program, I need to detect whether I'm in a Unity desktop or not. Is this possible? Is it possible when I don't have access to the environment?

Comment: Found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70296/is-there-an-environment-variable-that-is-set-for-unity

Comment: I've edited my question, I may not have access to the environment, so that is not a complete solution.

Comment: Another way would be to check if a process named 'unity' is running. I don't think there's a cross-platform way to do this. For Linux, you may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's also XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP:

```
rubiojr@rubiojr-VirtualBox:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
Unity
```

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/70296/is-there-an-environment-variable-that-is-set-for-unity

Comment: Yes, this is in the output of `env`.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu you can use following commands:

- **echo $DESKTOP_SESSION**: This command return ubuntu when you are using Unity and ubuntu-2d when you are using Unity 2D and ...
- **sudo grep "Starting session" /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log**: Because of last version of Ubuntu use lightdm as display manager you can see **last line** of the lightdm.log file.

Answer (score 2):

Just shell execute `ps aux | grep unity`, this is cross-plattform for linux. Even works on ARM cores.

On my 11.04 Ubuntu running unity it returns unity-2d-panel, unity-2d-launcher and more processes. Can't confirm if this is true on every linux platform.

Comment: There can be other sessions (belonging to the current user or a different user) running Unity when your current session may not be it.  I would advise against relying on existence of a Unity process.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the list of environment variables for unity by running this command line:

```
env | grep -i unity
```

If as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526460/1091386) you see `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` then you know it is in use. Alternatively, you could of course check for `desktop` rather than `unity`.