# finding absolute path name of a process on macOS

Tags: macos, go

I am new in GO and mac,
and I'm trying to use sysctl for finding the full path name of running processes.

```
kprocs, err := unix.SysctlKinfoProcSlice("kern.proc.all")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }

    for _, proc := range kprocs {
        name := string(proc.Proc.P_comm[:])
        pid := proc.Proc.P_pid
        extName, err := unix.SysctlKinfoProc("kern.proc.pathname", int(pid))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error: ", err)
        }
```

and getting error:  no such file or directory

am I using this function correcly?

**EDIT**
If I run the process like this: ./processName ,then I am not getting it's full path, for example /Users/username/go/src/processName - which is what I need.
All the solutions with `ps` will give the **relative** path, and I need someting that gives the **absolute** path of the process.

Comment: No silly mistake indeed. I've reproduced your error. You're getting all processes info together with the error line right ? (meaning if you comment `extName` there are no errors).

Comment: For the processes which get the `ENOENT` error, the `unix.SysctlKinfoProc("kern.proc.pathname", int(pid))` value is `nil`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73191486/152016, change `process.Name()` to `process.Cmdline()`

Comment: @niloct, I tried that but, if I run the process like this: ./processName , then I am not getting it's full path, for example /Users/username/go/src/processName - which is what I need

Comment: So your use case is not that you need other processes' info, but only the absolute path of your running golang app ? Then check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70491592/152016

Comment: I am getting my own process path from os.Executable(). But I need other processes absolute path to compare to my own process absolute path

Comment: You could call `dirname $(realpath filename)` bash script, for each filename.

Comment: If you have the process ID you can use `lsof` to retrieve the full path of the process. With a bit of searching and stripping you get the full path of the command:`PROCESS_ID=123 lsof -p $PROCESS_ID -Fn | awk 'NR==5{print}' | sed "s/n\//\//"`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511864/get-real-path-of-application-from-pid

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
func printPath(pid int32) {
    cmd := exec.Command("ps", append([]string{"xuwww", "-p", strconv.Itoa(int(pid))})...)
    output, e := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
    lines := strings.Split(string(output), "\n")
    comps := strings.Fields(lines[1])

    fmt.Println(comps[len(comps)-1])
}

func main() {
    kprocs, err := unix.SysctlKinfoProcSlice("kern.proc.all")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }

    for _, proc := range kprocs {
        pid := proc.Proc.P_pid
        printPath(pid)
    }
}
```

I didn't use unix.SysctlKinfoProc(), instead ran a shell command `ps xuwww -p PID` using exec.command(). It returns output as string. Parse the output string to get absolute path.

Output:

`649 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMDPersistence.framework/XPCServices/IMDPersistenceAgent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/IMDPersistenceAgent 646 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKit.framework/Versions/A/Support/akd 643 /System/Library/CoreServices/pbs`

Comment: I tried this and I am getting "panic: runtime error: index out of range [-1]"

And more then that: If I run the process like this:  ./processName  , then I am not getting it's full path, for example /Users/username/go/src/processName - which is what I need

Comment: Why did you not use `unix.SysctlKinfoProc()` here ?

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment on your question you can get the information you are looking for by using [lsof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511864/get-real-path-of-application-from-pid).

Similar to the other code example you can iterate over all known processes but for some processes it takes some time for the command to return.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func printPath(pid int32) {
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("lsof -p %d -Fn | awk 'NR==5{print}' | sed \"s/n\\//\\//\"", pid))
    output, e := cmd.Output()
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", output)
}

func main() {
    kprocs, err := unix.SysctlKinfoProcSlice("kern.proc.all")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }

    for _, proc := range kprocs {
        pid := proc.Proc.P_pid
        fmt.Printf("getting for pid %d: ", pid)
        printPath(pid)
    }
}
```

The code output can be improved. Processes that have exited already now make the output kind of a mess :-/