# Is there a portable way to check if the process with a specific PID is still running?

Tags: c++, process

I was hoping for something as simple as this:

```
bool SomePortableLib::IsProcessWithPIDAlive(uint32_t PID);
```

Is the only way to implement something like this?

```
 // Warning! untested.
 bool IsProcessWithPIDAlive(uint32_t PID) {
     #if defined(WIN32)
          // Credit: [1]
          HANDLE process = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid);
          DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(process, 0);
          CloseHandle(process);
          return ret == WAIT_TIMEOUT;
     #elif defined(LINUX) || defined(QNX)
          // Credit: [2]
          struct stat sts;
          if (stat("/proc/<pid>", &sts) == -1 && errno == ENOENT) {
              return false;
          }
          return true;
     #elif ...
```

*[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591371/1294207
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153189/1294207*

Or is there a portable lib that does this? If not why not?

*I noticed that `boost` has a (non-official) process lib [boost::process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) but it doesn't look to currently support this either.*

*Note:* I am interested in a `c++03` implementation of this, but welcome answers with `c++11-17` as well.

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ standard regarding processes and pids. As such, by definition, there is no "portable" way to implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: How portable do you need it to be? There may not be a way of doing this on all systems ever, but if not that, perhaps one that covers a few major OS's would be good enough?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I figured that. But i thought that someone would have implemented something stable for this at some point. It is weird to me that something as simple as checking a process exists (since separate processes exist on essentially every OS) doesn't have a standard way. Does everyone always implement their own lib for this?

Comment: @DavidZ For my specific purpose, i need it on Windows, QNX and Nucleus. Nucleus is an obscure enough OS that i will probably have to implement this myself anyway, but i was interested in why this doesn't exist.

Comment: Tihs doesn't exist for the same reason why pink elephants don't exist: nobody has bothered to buy enough pink paint, and spend some time painting an elephant pink.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you think that is the answer then add it. Its a pain though given how old and mature processes are ...

Comment: Where are you getting your PIDs from?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Passed from the parent program, or sent through a pipe, or looked up in a file. Not sure what the relevance is?

Comment: My thinking was that if you're creating the process, you'd have an object with a handle or PID or something in it.  The existing process libraries seem to have this concept in mind.  The use case for "is this process that I did not create still running?" is not a common one.  Looks like you've got the start for creating your own library/add-on.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm In my specific case I am looking if my parent has died and am committing suicide if it has. I know this could be achieved with better methods, like a heartbeat or similar. But it brought up the general question for me of simply checking if a PID is alive or not.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox The problem with checking whether the parent process still exists is that there is race where the parent could die, a new process is created with the same PID, and then the child process checks for the existence of a process the parent PID. Better to use something like a pipe, and detect when it is closed because the parent exited.