# kill(in c) VS getpid VS stat

Tags: c

I want to know if a process on my computer exists.
There are three ways to test this through code in C:
kill,
getpid (pid)
,stat (path, & stat)

I want to know what are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: By stat do you mean checking for `/proc/<pid>`?

Comment: Uhm... `getpid()` doesn't take a parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if process exists given its pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152979/check-if-process-exists-given-its-pid)

Comment: The `getpid()` function tells you the PID of the current process.  You know the current process exists – if it didn't, it couldn't execute `getpid()` (or any other function).

Answer (score 4):

`kill(pid, 0)` is POSIX compliant whereas `stat("/proc/<pid>", ...)` is not.

I don't know what you mean with `getpid()` as it doesn't take any parameters.

---

**Update**:

`getpgid(pid)` is POSIX compliant as well, so I don't think there's a difference between using `kill` and `getpgid` for your purpose. I would choose `kill` because it's more widely used.

Comment: ok..
but getpid(<other pid>) <0
if true, the process is not alive.

what the adventeges and disadventeges?

Comment: `getpid()` returns the process ID of the **current** process. It doesn't check if any  other process is running.

Comment: getpgid this what i mean

Comment: @NetanelShimoni Thanks for clarifying, I have updated my answer.