# How to check the state of Linux threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading

How could I check the state of a Linux threads using codes, not tools? I want to know if a thread is running, blocked on a lock, or asleep for some other reason. I know the Linux tool "top" could do this work. But how to implement it in my own codes. Thanks.

Comment: Is parsing `top` output an option? :-)

Answer (score 8):

I think you should study in details the [/proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) file system, also documented [here, inside kernel source tree](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

It is the way the Linux kernel tells things to outside!

There is a `libproc` also (used by `ps` and `top`, which reads `/proc/` pseudo-files).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes), related to yours.

Reading files under `/proc/` don't do any disk I/O (because `/proc/` is a pseudo file system), so goes fast.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your process id is 100.

Go to `/proc/100/task` directory and there you could see multiple directories representing each threads.

then inside each subdirectory e.g. `/proc/100/task/10100` there is a file named `status`.

the 2nd line inside this file is the state information of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could also find it with by looking at the cgroup hierarchy of the service that your process belongs. Cgroups have a file called "tasks" and this file lists all the tasks of a service.

For example:

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/hello.service/tasks

Note: cgroup should be enabled in your linux kernel.