# Get process name on specified port

Tags: c++, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux API to list running processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes)

I have question. I make small program under linux in c++. I want to get process name, which is listening on some port. The process is running on server. I create connection using sockets and connect to specified port. Is it possible to get process name listening on port?
example:
./myapp www.example.com -p 100

Thanks for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/939855/643500 .. check both answers ..

Comment: If this isn't a programming question then it belongs at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it possible to get info about process? I have to send any request to the port?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

Comment: But I have to connect on port and get listening process name on this port. I don't know, if for this is some request. Or something with packet sniffing?

Comment: Get the list then parse\regex to extract what you need.