# Detect if pid is zombie on Linux

Tags: linux, popen, zombie-process

We can detect if some  is a zombie process via shell command line

```
ps ef -o pid,stat | grep <pid> | grep Z
```

To get that info in our C/C++ programs we use `popen()`, but we would like to avoid using `popen()`.  Is there a way to get the same result without spawning additional processes?

We are using Linux 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem. Access to files inside it (e.g. `/proc/1234/stat` ...) is really fast (it does not involve any physical I/O).

You probably want the third field from `/proc/1234/stat` (which is readable by everyone, but you should read it sequentially, since it is unseekable.). If that field is `Z` then process of pid 1234 is zombie.

No need to fork a process (e.g. with`popen` or `system`), in C you might code

```
pid_t somepid;
// put the process pid you are interested in into somepid

bool iszombie = false;
// open the /proc/*/stat file
char pbuf[32];
snprintf(pbuf, sizeof(pbuf), "/proc/%d/stat", (int) somepid);
FILE* fpstat = fopen(pbuf, "r");
if (!fpstat) { perror(pbuf); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
{
  int rpid =0; char rcmd[32]; char rstatc = 0;
  fscanf(fpstat, "%d %30s %c", &rpid, rcmd, &rstatc); 
  iszombie = rstatc == 'Z';
}
fclose(fpstat);
```

Consider also `procps` and `libproc` so see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939855/841108).

(You could also read the second line of `/proc/1234/status` but this is probably harder to parse in C or C++ code)

BTW, I find that the `stat` file in `/proc/` has a weird format: if your executable happens to contain both spaces and parenthesis in its name (which is disgusting, but permitted) parsing the `/proc/*/stat` file becomes tricky.

Comment: Thanks, but also in this case we need to use popen() in C/C++ program. I need to avoid using popen()

Comment: @Alex: You do not need `popen()` to access `/proc`, just use ordinary `open()` or `fopen()`.

Comment: One more question. Can I read proc/<pid>/proc if I don't have permissions to work with <pid>? <pid> may be process of another owner.

Comment: Yes you can read the `/proc/1234/stat` of some process not belonging to you.

Comment: Also if permissions of the executable are 700? And executable is not mine?

Comment: Yes, even for system processes not belonging to you the `/proc/1234/stat` file is *world* readable. And on some systems (e.g. SELinux) where you cannot read it, you should not care about that process (because you cannot do anything about it).

Comment: It seemts that it works also if permissions of the executable are 700 and executable is not mine. Thanks