# Exec - shell_exec - translate output to progress bar

Tags: php, jquery, process, background-process, execute

I have two functions, one runs a thread in the background with `exec()` and returns output

```
function runThread($cmd, $priority = 0){
    if($priority){
        exec(sprintf('nohup nice -n %s %d > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! &',$priority, $cmd),$pid);
    }else{
        exec(sprintf('nohup %s > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! &',$cmd),$pid);
    }
    return $pid[0];
}
```

The other monitors the thread using `shell_exec()` and returns false when it completes

```
function isRunning($pid){
    try{
        $result = shell_exec(sprintf("ps %s", $pid));
        if( count(preg_split("/\n/", $result)) > 2){
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){}

    return false;
}
```

Instead of returning true or false, I'd like to return values based off the time it takes to run the entire thread so I can incorporate an AJAX progress bar e.g. return 20%, return 40% etc..  Is this possible with `shell_exec()` or should I use something like `proc_open()` and how can the current state of the thread be returned in real time?

Thanks for your help

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes