# getting child processes with libproc

Tags: c, linux, process

Like adviced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939855/1035445) I use `libproc` to get a list of all running processes. In comparison to the treeview of `htop` miss I the ability to get all child processes of a parent process. Is there a way or function to get them?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the parent-pid from the child's info provided by `/proc/<child-pid>/stat`.

As far as I know `/proc` does not provide this info the other way round.

---

To get the tree just read in the parent-pid attribute for all pids and then build up the reverse index yourself.

Comment: One of the main problems is that the `/proc` (and the `libproc` also) didn't lists the child-pids at all. So I only get the parent-pids and not the child-pids.

Comment: @arbyter: Yes sure, but knowing who is the parent-pid of a pid makes you know that this pid is the child of what it carries as it's parent. So you are capable to build the tree your own, **after** you read out the parent-pid for **all* pids.

Answer (score 0):

In `/proc/<pid>/task` I have found what I had searched for. All child-processes are listed there. Unfortunately I have to write my own code to get the infos out of the structure, but that should be manageable :).

Answer (score 0):

If you're struck using `libproc` (e.g. on systems without linux's `/proc` filesystem), you can use `proc_listpids`.

XNU (macOS' kernel) also offers [`proc_listchildpids`](https://github.com/apple-opensource/xnu/blob/24525736ba5b8a67ce3a8a017ced469abe101ad5/libsyscall/wrappers/libproc/libproc.c#L86-L96), which just calls `proc_listpids`, but returning the number of PIDs instead of raw byte count.

```
int
proc_listchildpids(pid_t ppid, void * buffer, int buffersize)
{
    int numpids;
    numpids = proc_listpids(PROC_PPID_ONLY, (uint32_t)ppid, buffer, buffersize);
    if (numpids == -1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return numpids / sizeof(int);
    }
}
```

I feel like that's more of a trap than a convience, so I just prefered to call `proc_listpids` directly, myself.