# how to use the bash commands in C?

Tags: c, bash, ulimit

I was actually searching for the way to execute the output of bash built-in commands through a C program. Specifically I want to get the output of no.of processes running in the system through a C program . I found the command , now I want to get that through a C code .
Can anyone help me out of this ?

Comment: Why don't you use the `getrlimit` system call?

Comment: Is it to get the no.of processes running in the system??

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes

Comment: How does `ulimit` give you that information?

Comment: `ulimit -u` was giving the maximum no.of process that are available for the user

Comment: Yes, and you can get the same information with `getrlimit`. But that's not the number of processes currently running, what is how I understood your question.

Comment: run the desired command via the system() call with piping the output of the command to a file.  Then have your program open that file for read/input.  Then read the contents of the file, Then for cleanup, use a system() call to delete the file.