# Is there an alternative to find the running processes in linux other than terminal parsing using ps command

Tags: c++, linux, process

For a CPP application in linux, I need the running processes list, their PID , The port they are running on, and the location of the .exe file where it is started from.

I can use PS command, But I want it in a CPP application. Using System command and parsing the output is not recommended.

Does Linux store these information somewhere from where I can read or is there some native API's which I can make use of like win32 api's in windows.

Comment: You have to write `ps` alike tool. All processes are list under `/proc` in GNU/Linux.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `libproc-dev`.

> The /proc interface provides access to the state of each user-level
>   process and thread also known as lightweight process or lwp in the
>   system. It also provides the ability to control such processes and
>   threads. It is a low-level interface.
>
> The libproc library provides a higher-level interface to the features
>   of the /proc interface as well as access to information such as symbol
>   tables which is necessary for the examination and control of processes
>   and threads. For more information, see the proc(5) man page.

Take a look at some  [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37842/libproc-3lib.html)

Comment: Example: for proc in /proc/*/cmdline; do echo $(basename $(dirname $proc)) $(cat $proc | tr "\0" " "); done - From: https://pet2cattle.com/2021/12/docker-ps-command-not-found