# Is there any C function or API to get the list of process running under the current log in user

Tags: c++, c, windows

i am writing a code to search whether the given .exe file is running under the specific user account or  not. 
Is  there any API to get the list of process running under the specific user. or else can we get the user name of the process from the process in C++.

I did some search from the internet and found that "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" will help. But its returning all the process that runs under all users in the system. I want the process that runs under the specific user to be printed.

Comment: Please avoid the term "C/C++". There is no such language, and many of us old-timers actively dislike it. If you're writing a C++ program, then use only the `c++` tag.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes) help?

Comment: @uneven_mark... I am looking for windows specific.

Comment: Using Win32_Process WMI Class you get the process runing and with the GetOwner command you will get the user id of each process. See this link to know how to access to WMI [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-c---application-examples)

Comment: you need under same user sid ? under same logon session ?

Comment: @SuperG280 - what sense use wmi at all when possible direct use api which use wmi ?

Comment: and `GetOwner` (if it query *TokenOwner*) absolute wrong. need look for *TokenUser* if need user sid

Comment: Keep in mind, that a user can rename an executable image. Whatever you had planned to identify that executable is probably not going to work. With that, this totally reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

> I am writing a code to search whether the given .exe file is running
>   under the specific user account or not.

Use [`OpenProcessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken) to get the token (obviously), then [`GetTokenInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) with the `TokenUser` flag to get the SID of the owner. Then you can use [`LsaLookupSids2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalookupsids2) to get the username.

> Is there any API to get the list of process running under the specific
>   user... But `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` returning all the process that
>   runs under all users in the system.

You can filter out the specified user from it by the above method.

Comment: why *TokenOwner* when we need *TokenUser* here. if want get user account. and `LookupAccountSid` not good by design api, better use `LsaLookupSids`

Comment: @RbMm, Thanks for pointer out, fixed. And used the `LsaLookupSids2 ` instead of `LsaLookupSids` since It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions.