# How to redirect the output of system() called in a C program to syslog?

Tags: c, output, system, syslog

Inside my **C** code I call `system` to have result from a bash command.

I.e. `system("ps aux | grep my_prog | head -n 1")`

All is fine when I run my program in *foreground* mode, but in production is a *service*, so I need to see the output of `system` in `syslog`, not on `stdout` or `stderr`.

I'm struggling to find the best and least painful option here.
Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: "Least painful" greatly depends on your perspective.  What may be the simplest changes for you to make now could very well be extremely painful down the road.  For example `system( "sh -c 'ps aux | grep my_prog | sed 1q | logger'");` may seem painless now, but could lead to weeping and gnashing of teeth in the future.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell , that's eaxactly why I wrote about the "pain", because I saw the `logger` option but I don't want to it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to use `popen()` instead of `system()` and then the syslog interface, `man 3 syslog`:

```
NAME
   closelog, openlog, syslog - send messages to the system logger

SYNOPSIS
   #include <syslog.h>

   void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
   void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
   void closelog(void);

   #include <stdarg.h>

   void vsyslog(int priority, const char *format, va_list ap);
```

Also note that grepping `ps` output has its pitfalls (e.g. it may also return the `grep` process first). Why not search for the proper process in the C code iterating over `ps` output? Or directly iterate over the process table using functions your OS provides?

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented as you suggested and it works. Could you give me additional explanation on your notes about the `ps` pitfalls, not sure i understood. Thanks

Comment: @Kyrol A simple grep for process my_prog will usually return at least two matches. The `head -n 1` selects the first, but how do you know ps does not return the grep process first? It's an assumption you make that might become false.

Comment: I got your point. So, how can I iterate over the process table in my C code. I never did that, is something new. Any hints ? Thank you

Comment: @Kyrol On my system, FreeBSD, I can ask the kernel for the process table with `kvm_getprocs()`. For Linux, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778 is a starting point. But it could be enough to just use `popen("ps aux")` and then use strcmp() to find the interesting process.